# Sobolev (Triebel-Lizorkin) norm estimate for $F \circ u - F \circ v$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sobolev-spaces, estimation-theory, besov-spaces

Let $F \in C^1(\mathbb R^d;\mathbb R)$ be such that $F(0) = 0$ and
$$|F'(\tau v + (1 - \tau)w)| \leq \mu(\tau)(G(v) + G(w))$$
for some $\mu \in L^1([0,1])$ and some non-negative $G \in C^0(\mathbb R^d;\mathbb R)$.

Assume that $s \in ]0,1[$, $p \in ]1,\infty[$, $q_1 \in ]1,\infty]$, $q_2 \in ]1,\infty[$, $1/p = 1/q_1 + 1/q_2$.

Then if $u \in H^{s,q_2}(\mathbb R^d)$ and $G \circ u \in L^{q_1}(\mathbb R^d)$, it is shown in Chapter 2.5 of M. Taylor "Tools for PDE" that $F \circ u \in H^{s,p}(\mathbb R^d)$ and

\begin{equation}\|F \circ u\|_{H^{s,p}} \leq C \cdot \|G \circ u\|_{L^{q_1}} \cdot \|u\|_{H^{s,q_2}}\tag{0}\end{equation}

for some constant $C > 0$ independent of $u$.

I'm interested in proving an estimate of the form
\begin{equation}
\|F \circ u - F \circ v\|_{H^{s,p}}  \leq C \cdot \left( \|G \circ u\|_{L^{q_1}} + \|G \circ v\|_{L^{q_1}} \right) \cdot \|u - v\|_{H^{s,q_2}}
\tag{1}\end{equation}
given similar hypotheses.

I've tried to adapt Taylor's proof, but I wasn't successful.

I've tried to write the difference as a product $$F\circ u - F \circ v = (u-v)\int_0^1 F'(\tau u + (1 - \tau) v)d\tau$$
but the paraproduct estimates given in Taylor's book are not sufficient.

I'm mostly interested in the polynomial case where $F(x) = |x|^{p-1}x$ with $p \in \mathbb R_{\geq 1}$. I cannot assume that $F$ or $F'$ is $L^{\infty}$, that $F \in C^2$ or that the domain we are working on is bounded.

Any help or reference is welcomed !

---

EDIT :

As pointed out by T. Tao, as such, the estimate is not going to be true. Let's focus to the case $F(x) = |x|^{a-1}x$ with $1 < a < 2$.

Would such an estimate be true ?

\begin{equation}
\|F \circ u - F \circ v\|_{H^{s,p}} \leq C \cdot \left( \|u\|_{H^{s,p}} + \|v\|_{H^{s,p}} \right)^{a-1} \cdot \|u - v\|_{H^{s,p}}\tag{2}\end{equation}

I want to apply such an inequality in a fixed point argument for the critical wave equation $\square u = \pm |u|^{a-1}u$ in high dimension and with small initial data in $\dot{H}^{1,2} \times L^2$ (homogeneous setting).

I've looked at Lindblad-Sogge paper (mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1335386). An inequality, which looks similar to $(1)$, is used in the proof of Lemma 4.1. They invoke Proposition 3.5 to justify it, but in that proposition, they only prove the fractional chain rule $(0)$.

I've also looked at L. Kapitanski paper (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03605309408821067). Here, they split $F$ into two parts : the part around the origin, which is Lipschitz, and the part away from the origin, which is $C^{\infty}$.

However, they claim in Theorem 3.3 that if $F$ is Lipschitz, then the equation $\square u = F(u)$, given initial data in $H^{1,2} \times L^2$, has a global solution, which is found via a fixed point procedure. Again, I don't understand how to justify the fixed point procedure. Even if $F$ is Lipschitz, an inequality like $(1)$ (with $\|G \circ u\|_{L^{q_1}} + \|G \circ v\|_{L^{q_1}}$ replaced by the Lipschitz constant of $F$), should not hold.

Comment: This estimate is not going to be true in general.  Linearising by setting $u = v + \varepsilon w$ for an infinitesimal $\varepsilon$, your claimed estimate would imply that $\| w (F' \circ v) \|_{H^{s,p}} \lesssim \| G \circ v \|_{q_1} \| w \|_{H^{s,q_2}}$ which on setting $w$ to be a bump function is clearly going to be false (RHS requires no regularity on $v$ but LHS demands $s$ orders of regularity).  Probably the estimate one obtains from the Leibniz rule and your product representation is the best one can hope for.

Comment: @TerryTao Thanks for pointing this out. Do you happen to know (or have a reference) on how to prove that for small initial data, the energy critical wave equation $\square u = \pm |u|^{p-1}u$ has a global solution (in a high dimension where $1 < p < 2$) ? I've read that it follows from Strichartz estimates and a contraction argument, but I cannot get my head around how to justify the contraction. That's what was behind this question of mine.

Comment: I would imagine the Lindblad-Sogge paper https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1335386 would have a proof of this for suitable $n,p$, though I haven't checked.  I think the paraproduct method you indicated together with Sobolev embedding will still be able to obtain estimates of the form $\|F(u)-F(v)\|_{H^{s,r}} \ll ( \| u \|_{H^{s,q}} + \|v\|_{H^{s,q}})^{p-1} \| u-v \|_{H^{s,q}}$ for various exponents $q,r,s$ which should still suffice to create a contraction in a suitable spacetime Sobolev type space.

Comment: Now that I think about it, there are indeed some technical issues in the $1<a<2$ case.  Take a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4534 which treats the energy-critical case of this problem and establishes suitable variants of the estimate you seek.

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you very much, it seems to be exactly what I was looking for.